# Возможно ли сделать паузу в цикле C#?

Tags: c#, циклы

У меня есть цикл и если у меня переменная меньше 0, то мне нужно, чтобы высвечивалась новая форма, а цикл ждал пока я не закончу работать с формой.
Возможно ли это сделать?

```
while ((i <= 1000) && (auto.bak > 0))
{                       
    if ((auto.bak < 10)&&(auto.bak>0)) 
    {
        Random zpr = new Random();
        int zapr = zpr.Next(1, 10);
        if (auto.bak>=zapr)
        {

        } 
        else
        {
            car.go(zapr);
            //при выполнении этого условия, мне нужно чтобы цикл вставал на паузу и выполнялась функция car.go(zapr);
        }                           
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Не делайте так в цикле `Random zpr = new Random();`, иначе будете жаловаться сюда, что у вас вместо случайного числа появляется одно и тоже число. 2) необходимую вам форму можно отобразить  как диалоговое c пом. метода `ShowDialog()`, т.е. пока пользователь не закроет диалоговое окно он не сможет вернуться к главной форме.

Comment: А куда лучше вставлять random?

Comment: Вы должны в цикле вызывать только `Next(...)`, а переменную нужно инициализировать до начала цикла, а лучше вообще на уровне класса.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это WinForms приложение, то форму следует показывать используя метод ShowDialog. Цикл не будет выполняться до тех пор, пока такую форму не закроют.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не подходит ответ выше - тогда вам подойдет класс AutoResetEvent
Пример можно увидеть тут - https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/thread_and_files/1/1_12.php